# git submodules need commit from super project?

Tags: git

I have a git project repo that contains two other projects as submodules.  When ever modifications are made to files in the submodules, when moving out to the "super project", the owner of the submodules--- git status shows

```
modified:   on_of_my_submodules (new commits)
```

...  I find this to be very strange, and annoying...  Any time a commit is made in one of these submodules, I have to go out of the directory and commit it as well?  Is this really the workflow that everyone does when working with submodules?

I am tempted to attempt adding the submodules to my super project's .gitignore, and just know that when cloning the super project it's necessary to go into all the submodules and pull from there to get the latest stuff.

I would love to hear some insight on how to deal with this properly...

Answer (score 0):

The superproject is locked to a specific commit in a submodule; whenever a new commit is made in the submodule, and you want the superproject to be locked to that commit, you have to commit that change.

(This is actually very helpful, as it ties a specific commit in the superproject to a specific commit in the submodule.)

Comment: but you don't find it tedious and annoying to have the workflow of:  (work).. git commit -am "implemented feature X";  git push origin master; cd ../..;  git commit -am "updating submodule junk"; git push origin master;    ... ?

Comment: it seems like that workflow just puts a billion worthless commits in the super project.

Comment: @patrick: I only update the superproject when I'm prepared to tie it to a new version of the submodule (so not just for every commit).